# Necessity of testing key value before calling IsDialogMessage

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dialog, message-loop

I've seen [several](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e4a977d-e09a-4a39-b94f-1d7f8ab21a3d/tab-key-in-modalles-form?forum=winforms) [code](https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/IsDialogMessage/cpp-isdialogmessage-function-examples.html) [examples](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/187/Q187988/) that test the value of a message to determine that it's between `WM_KEYFIRST` and `WM_KEYLAST` before calling `IsDialogMessage`.

I was wondering if that's technically necessary.  Wouldn't  `IsDialogMessage` inherently do that?  Or is it more efficient perhaps to test the value before calling the function?

Comment: `IsDialogMessage` processes at least one non-key message (`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`) that I know of, so it seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use the WM_KEYFIRST and WM_KEYLAST messages to filter for keyboard messages when using the GetMessage and PeekMessage functions.

When IsDialogMessage processes a message, it checks for keyboard messages and converts them into selections for the corresponding dialog box.

As far as I'm concerned, It is unnecessary to test the key value before calling IsDialogMessage.

For more details about [IsDialogMessageA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isdialogmessagea),I suggest you could refer to the doc:[Why do we need IsDialogMessage at all?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120416-00/?p=7853)